# How can I access s3 file with ACL private with node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am using Node.JS with S3 to store report files,

I upload file to S3 with private ACL. 
I can view the file with security token on the admin console.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>84319E5010B9XXXX</RequestId>
<HostId>XXXX</HostId>
</Error>
```

But how to access or read the file on Node JS.

Can someone give me any advice ?

Thanks

More information

I use S3.getObject from and here is the errors

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAI5GZX6FPWYHUSYJA</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>GET 1535990810 /scb-villa-dev/report/jake.jpg</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>me9v6CiqNulgDWO4nrJX3db926Y=</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>
47 45 54 0a 0a 0a 31 35 33 35 39 39 30 38 31 30 0a 2f 73 63 62 2d 76 69 6c 6c 61 2d 64 65 76 2f 72 65 70 6f 72 74 2f 6a 61 6b 65 2e 6a 70 67
</StringToSignBytes>
<RequestId>26FF2695AC752DED</RequestId>
<HostId>
KIldHSpZOHgm3ancrVOETYRQ+BhYb6pcFtJXhJ+jv/XWk73C3J0yQfZDa24doV7ORUmi98/lS7Q=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Thanks again.

Comment: you have to grant permission to the account you are using in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Go to [IAM](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home) and change the permission for your user account.

Comment: How I can access it with amazon authentication by node js ?

Comment: you must have use key for s3 instance. you need to change the access level of this key

Comment: are you using aws-sdk?